# Cannot Decrypt the encrypted columns from the database backup on local machine

Tags: sql, sql-server, encryption, sql-server-2014

I've a SQL server 2014 running on one of our server. We're in the process of implementing security steps for our databases. I've encrypted a column in one of the table in the database on the server. The issue is when I restore the backup on my local SQL server and run a query to decrypt the column data it gives me null values. On the other end when I decrypt the column data on the main server it works fine. I found a thread on this forum which states to do the following when restoring the encrypted database on different server.

```
USE [master];
  GO

OPEN MASTER KEY DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'StrongPassword';
ALTER MASTER KEY ADD ENCRYPTION BY SERVICE MASTER KEY;
GO 

select File_Name
, CONVERT(nvarchar,DECRYPTBYKEY(File_Name)) 
 from [test].[dbo].[Orders_Customer]
```

I tried doing above still no luck.

Can anybody point me in the right direction? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: should you not know the KEY used to encrypt the column on the server? You should use the same KEY to restore it on your local instance as well.

Comment: @vkp- I tried creating similar key and certificates on my local sql server. Followed exact steps I performed on my main server still I get null values instead of decrypted values on my local machine. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need the actual key from the server to read the values, not just a similar key and certificate, as cryptographically, they aren't similar at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've opened the Master key (in your example) in the Master DB

Change the first line to use

```
Use Test;
```

The **Open Master Key** statement works in the context of the Current Database. You opened it whilst in Master, but then selected that data from the Test DB.